# Exsheets package: use the chapter name in chapter-hook option

Tags: exsheets

I am typesetting a problems book with the `exsheets` package. I want the structure of solutions to repeat the structure of the problems set. `Chapter-hook` and `section-hook` options allow to add custom code to the list of solutions when the solutions of a new chapter/section are printed. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{part} % Reset \chapter numbering after each \part
\makeatother  
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  chapter-hook = \chapter{Solutions to the chapter \thechapter},
  section-hook = \section{Solutions to the section \thesection},
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Problems}
  \chapter{Mechanics}
    \section{Kinematics}
      \begin{question}
        A kinematics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the kinematics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

    \section{Dynamics}
      \begin{question}
        A dynamics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the dynamics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

  \chapter{Electricity}
    \section{Electrostatics}
      \begin{question}
        An electrostatics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the electrostatics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

    \section{Electrodynamics}
      \begin{question}
        An electrodynamics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the electrodynamics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

\part{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Produced table of contents is as follows: [image: toc]

What I'd like to achieve is to have `1  Solutions to Mechanics` instead of current `1  Solutions to the chapter 1`, `2  Solutions to Electricity` instead of `2  Solutions to the chapter 2` and so on. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution via references of package `nameref`. The chapter/section number is used as label name.

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{part} % Reset \chapter numbering after each \part
\makeatother
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{nameref}
\SetupExSheets{
  chapter-hook = \chapter{Solutions to \nameref{CHAP:\thechapter}},
  section-hook = \section{Solutions to \nameref{SEC:\thesection}},
}
\newcommand*{\chaplabel}{\label{CHAP:\thechapter}}
\newcommand*{\seclabel}{\label{SEC:\thesection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Problems}
  \chapter{Mechanics}\chaplabel
    \section{Kinematics}\seclabel
      \begin{question}
        A kinematics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the kinematics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

    \section{Dynamics}\seclabel
      \begin{question}
        A dynamics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the dynamics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

  \chapter{Electricity}\chaplabel
    \section{Electrostatics}\seclabel
      \begin{question}
        An electrostatics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the electrostatics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

    \section{Electrodynamics}\seclabel
      \begin{question}
        An electrodynamics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the electrodynamics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

\part{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The label settings can be included in `\chapter` and `\section`:

- New command `\mychapter` that adds `\chaplabel`.
- Saving the old definition of `\chapter` (e.g. via package `letltxmacro`)
  and redefining `\chapter` to execute the saved version and appends `\chaplabel`.
- Depending on the needed argument types (star form, optional argument), the (re)definitions are more or less easy to more complicate.

Version, where `\chaplabel` and `\seclabel` are used in the `<after code>` argument of `\titleformat`, provided by package `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{part} % Reset \chapter numbering after each \part
\makeatother  
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{nameref}
\SetupExSheets{
  chapter-hook = \chapter{Solutions to \nameref{CHAP:\thechapter}},
  section-hook = \section{Solutions to \nameref{SEC:\thesection}},
}
\newcommand*{\chaplabel}{\label{CHAP:\thechapter}}
\newcommand*{\seclabel}{\label{SEC:\thesection}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}%
  {}[\chaplabel]
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}%
  {}[\seclabel]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\printsolutions{%
  \let\chaplabel\relax
  \let\seclabel\relax
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\printsolutions failed.}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Problems}
  \chapter{Mechanics}
    \section{Kinematics}
      \begin{question}
        A kinematics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the kinematics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

    \section{Dynamics}
      \begin{question}
        A dynamics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the dynamics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

  \chapter{Electricity}
    \section{Electrostatics}
      \begin{question}
        An electrostatics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the electrostatics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

    \section{Electrodynamics}
      \begin{question}
        An electrodynamics problem.
        \begin{solution}
          Solution to the electrodynamics problem.
        \end{solution}
      \end{question}

\part{Solutions}
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

The trick to avoid the infinite recursion as in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377466/exsheets-package-use-the-chapter-name-in-chapter-hook-option/377473?noredirect=1#comment935345_377473) is to disable `\chaplabel` and `\seclabel` before the chapters and sections of `\printsolutions` are processed.

Slight variation with a switch `\ifwithlabels`. Then the label setting can be disabled for unnumbered chapters, e.g.:

```
[...]
\newif\ifwithlabels
\newcommand*{\chaplabel}{\ifwithlabels\label{CHAP:\thechapter}\fi}
\newcommand*{\seclabel}{\ifwithlabels\label{SEC:\thesection}\fi}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}%
  {}[\chaplabel]
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}%
  {}[\seclabel]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\printsolutions{%
  \withlabelsfalse
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \noexpand\printsolutions failed.}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\withlabelstrue
\part{Problems}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks, the result is what I was looking for. But could you please elaborate on any way how to append `\chaplabel` automatically after every \chapter?  I tried to do it using `titlesec` package since I am using it anyway: `\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}[\chaplabel]`. However, it gives an error: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` If I change `[\chaplabel]` to some text, it compiles without errors and the text appears after every chapter name (but unfortunately also after `Contents`).